# How to i retrieve the firebase database child node with Name but not push id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the value for the selected child of the parent node which are not save using push id but name instead.

My firebase database : https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCEf.jpg

My current JS code:

```
 var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('Admin').child('AssignCarTowing');

  rootRef.on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function (snap) {


      //console.log(snapshot.key);
      //console.log(snap.key);

      var status = snap.child("Status").val();
      var name = snap.child("Name").val();
      var cnum = snap.child("CarNumber").val();
      var cmodel = snap.child("CarModel").val();
      var hp = snap.child("ContactNo").val();
      var brkloc = snap.child("BreakdownLocation").val();
      var dandt = snap.child("TowingDateandTime").val();
      var peric = snap.child("PersonInCharge").val();

      $("#towreqlist").append("<tr><td>" + status + "</td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + cmodel +
        "</td><td>" + cnum + "</td><td>" + dandt +
        "</td><td>" + hp + "</td><td>" + brkloc + "</td><td>" + peric + "</td><td><button onclick='done(\"" + snapshot.key + "\", \"" + snap.key + "\")' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Done</button>");

    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding another ref on the node in my code

```
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref('Admin/Person In Charge/Towing/' + auth.currentUser.uid);
    rootRef.once('value', function (snap) {

      firebase.database().ref('Admin').child('AssignCarTowing').child(snap.child("Name").val()).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function (snap) {


          //console.log(snapshot.key);
          //console.log(snap.key);

          //var status = snap.child("Status").val();
          var name = snap.child("CustName").val();
          var cnum = snap.child("CustCarNumber").val();
          var cmodel = snap.child("CustCarModel").val();
          var hp = snap.child("CustContactNo").val();
          var brkloc = snap.child("CustLocation").val();
          var dandt = snap.child("CustBDTD").val();
          //var peric = snap.child("PersonInCharge").val();

          $("#towreqlist").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + cmodel +
            "</td><td>" + cnum + "</td><td>" + dandt +
            "</td><td>" + hp + "</td><td>" + brkloc + "</td><td><button onclick='done(\"" + snapshot.key + "\", \"" + snap.key + "\")' class='btn btn-success btn-sm'>Done</button>");

        });
      });

    })
```